# How can I focus a button on click with styled-components for React?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to do a simple thing: my buttons shall change the background color when clicked.

I am using styled-components and the pseudo-classes `:focus` `:visited` `:target` do not work. I also tried changing my `div` to an anchor link.

Weirdly, `:hover` does work but the ones mentioned above don't.

```
const Box = styled.div`
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 18px;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(17, 16, 62, 0.1);
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 700;
   border: 2px solid rgb(74, 165, 234);
   border-radius: 3px;
   background: white;
   cursor: pointer;

&:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(17, 16, 62, 0.15);
}

&:focus {
   background: rgb(104, 173, 226);
   color: white;
}`
```

I expected the button to change background colors once I click it. But it does nothing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs are not focusable. Either use an actual `<button>` (that would be `styled.button` of course), or give it a tabindex:

```css
div,
button {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

div:focus,
button:focus {
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div>div without tabindex</div>
<button>button</button>
<div tabindex="0">div with tabindex</div>
```

Focusable HTML elements: https://gist.github.com/jamiewilson/c3043f8c818b6b0ccffd

Tabindex values: https://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex